# Return 404 not found when form submit using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a simple AJAX call in "index.ejs" from my js file called "script.js". However, I keep getting an error. `POST http://localhost:3000/doLogin 404 (Not Found)`

In index.ejs:

```
<div id="login-page" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="login-form" action="/doLogin" method="post">
            <input id="txtEmailLogin" type="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input id="txtPasswordLogin" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In script.js:

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#login-page', function() {
    var frm = $('#login-form');
    frm.submit(function(e) {
        var email = $('#txtEmailLogin').val();
        var password = $('#txtPasswordLogin').val();

        $.ajax({
            type     : frm.attr('method'),
            url      : frm.attr('action'), 
            data     : {
                email    : email,
                password : password
            },
            success : function(check) {
                if (check.status == 'success') {
                    alert('Welcome, '+ check.name +' !');
                    $('body').pagecontainer('change', '/profile');
                }else {
                    alert('Fail to Login');
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: 404 means that there is no localhost:3000/doLogin - show us your server-side code if you think this path should be available

Comment: what happens if you visit this url in a browser tab?

Comment: Can you open browser debugger and check where exactly the request is sent? Note: when you submit, it resolves context path for you. But in jQuery, you sent directly to action path

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#login-page', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
var frm = $('#login-form');
frm.submit(function(e) {
    var email = $('#txtEmailLogin').val();
    var password = $('#txtPasswordLogin').val();

    $.ajax({
        type     : frm.attr('method'),
        url      : frm.attr('action'), 
        data     : {
            email    : email,
            password : password
        },
        success : function(check) {
            if (check.status == 'success') {
                alert('Welcome, '+ check.name +' !');
                $('body').pagecontainer('change', '/profile');
            }else {
                alert('Fail to Login');
            }
        }
    });
});});
```

use this 
Mention php file name in action